# The audit progress has not changed

Tags: linkedin-api

I created an app in Lingying's development zone. After applying for products, they failed

[Together in the audit status, for several days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuHnu.png)

Comment: Looks like your question is out of StackOverflow responsibilities. You can find a more relevant place at https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Not relevant for Stack Overflow